# How to split a series with array to multiple series?

Tags: pandas, numpy, split

One column of my dataset contains `numpy arrays` as elements. I want to split it to multiple columns each one with a value of the array.
Data now are like:

```
      column1            column2             column3
0        1         np.array([1,2,3,4])        4.5
1        2         np.array([5,6,7,8])         3
```

I want to convert it into:

```
   column1     col1 col2 col3 col4   column3
0     1         1    2    3    4       4.5
1     2         5    6    7    8        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution, based on [`pandas.DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_records):

```
out = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    df['col'], columns=[f'col{i+1}' for i in range(len(df.loc[0, 'col']))])
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     2     3     4
1     5     6     7     8
```

Comment: Thank you but what about when it is not the only column of the dataframe? I edited my post to make it clearer. Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have more than one column with `np.arrays`?

Comment: No but one of the columns contains np.array. The other are just numbers

Comment: So, you can use the following code (which was adapted from my previous answer): `pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['column2'], columns=[f'col{i+1}' for i in range(len(df.loc[0, 'column2']))])], axis=1).drop(columns='column2')`.

Comment: worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col':[np.array([1,2,3,4]),np.array([5,6,7,8])]})

new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.col.tolist(), index= df.index) #explode column to new dataframe and get index from old df.
new_df.columns = ["col_{}".format(i) for i in range(1,len(new_df.columns) + 1)]

'''
   col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
0      1      2      3      4
1      5      6      7      8
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your question well. You can leverage the `result_type="expand"` of the `.apply` method:

```py
df = df.apply(
    lambda x: {f"col{k}": vv for v in x for k, vv in enumerate(v, 1)},
    result_type="expand",
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     2     3     4
1     5     6     7     8
```

Comment: Thank you but what about when it is not the only column of the dataframq?